# Parse sequences in FASTA format with Perl

Tags: regex, shell, perl, bioinformatics, fasta

I have the following file where some of the records (each one separated by the line starting with ">") are in one line while others are among multiple lines:

```
>NODE_1506886_length_92_cov_1.000000
CATGCGAACTTCCGCAAGGACATCGTCATCCATGGCTTCAGACATGCCATGCGTGACCGT
CTGAGAGCCGTTAGCTGCCCATCAGAGATGAT
>NODE_1506887_length_92_cov_1.000000
TATATTTTAATTCATTATTTGGTACATCAAACGATGAGGCTAAATATATAATAACTGGAA
ATAATCGAGACGTAAATCGATACCGATGGAAC
>k119_811274 flag=1 multi=3.0000 len=313
TAAAAAATTACTACCTTGCAGATAAGTCGCTCAGCCCATGGTTGTCAGGTTTATCTGCAATGGCAACAAATAACAGTGGCTACATGTTTATTGGTCTTATTGGATTCACCTATCTCAATGGCCTTTCCAGCATATGGCTAATGATTGGTTGGATATTAGGGGATTACCTAATTACAAAAAAATTATTTCCAA
>k119_405638 flag=1 multi=7.0000 len=562
CACAGTTAACATAAATTACCACGAACGACGCACGCTCAAATCCGAAGCAAAGTCAGCAATTGCTAAATCCTGTTCAAAAAAAATTCCAAACGGTAGTTCGATATTTATCAATATCGGGACATCGACTGAAGCCGTCGCTCAGGAATTAATGCAGCACAGTAACTTAATGGTTGTGACCAACAACATAAATGTTGCCAATATTTTATCGCCCAATGAGAATTGTGAGATTCTTTTAACTGGTGGTCAACTTAGACGTTCTGACGGAGGTCTCATCGGTAATTTGGCAGC
```

I want to match only the the multi-line records and not the one-line records.
I have tried the following

```
perl -0777ne 's/(^[^>].+)\s[A-Z]/[$1]/s' file
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Try `perl -0777 -pe 's/^(?!>).+(?:\R[A-Z].*)+/[$&]/gm' file`

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew the output could be anything, I just want to check if there is a match for the multiline records and not the one-line ones. Thanks for the code, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: See https://ideone.com/BqoHnb and https://regex101.com/r/7CdBAk/1/, what does not work?

Comment: There are modules that can read these dna-string files. It might be worth your while to find such a module and use it.

Comment: Are you processing DNA sequences in FASTA format? If yes, try Bio::Perl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `>` as record separator instead of having to read entire file as single string

```
$ # to get records with more than one ACGT lines
$ perl -F'\n' -lane 'BEGIN{$/=">"; $\=""} print "$/$_" if $#F>1' ip.txt
>NODE_1506886_length_92_cov_1.000000
CATGCGAACTTCCGCAAGGACATCGTCATCCATGGCTTCAGACATGCCATGCGTGACCGT
CTGAGAGCCGTTAGCTGCCCATCAGAGATGAT
>NODE_1506887_length_92_cov_1.000000
TATATTTTAATTCATTATTTGGTACATCAAACGATGAGGCTAAATATATAATAACTGGAA
ATAATCGAGACGTAAATCGATACCGATGGAAC

$ # to get records with exactly one ACGT lines
$ perl -F'\n' -lane 'BEGIN{$/=">"; $\=""} print "$/$_" if $#F==1' ip.txt
>k119_811274 flag=1 multi=3.0000 len=313
TAAAAAATTACTACCTTGCAGATAAGTCGCTCAGCCCATGGTTGTCAGGTTTATCTGCAATGGCAACAAATAACAGTGGCTACATGTTTATTGGTCTTATTGGATTCACCTATCTCAATGGCCTTTCCAGCATATGGCTAATGATTGGTTGGATATTAGGGGATTACCTAATTACAAAAAAATTATTTCCAA
>k119_405638 flag=1 multi=7.0000 len=562
CACAGTTAACATAAATTACCACGAACGACGCACGCTCAAATCCGAAGCAAAGTCAGCAATTGCTAAATCCTGTTCAAAAAAAATTCCAAACGGTAGTTCGATATTTATCAATATCGGGACATCGACTGAAGCCGTCGCTCAGGAATTAATGCAGCACAGTAACTTAATGGTTGTGACCAACAACATAAATGTTGCCAATATTTTATCGCCCAATGAGAATTGTGAGATTCTTTTAACTGGTGGTCAACTTAGACGTTCTGACGGAGGTCTCATCGGTAATTTGGCAGC
```

- `-F'\n'` use newline as field separator, makes it easy to count number of lines per record
- `$/=">"; $\=""` set `>` as input record separator and empty string as output record separator
- `$#F>1` or `$#F==1` the required conditions

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Bio::SeqIO`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Bio::SeqIO) module from [BioPerl](https://bioperl.org/) to handle sequences in FASTA format. For example, this appends ".new" to ids, and changes sequences to lower case:

```
cat in.fa | \
    perl -MBio::SeqIO -e '
my $in_seq = Bio::SeqIO->new( -fh => \*STDIN, -format => "fasta", );
my $out_seq = Bio::SeqIO->new( -fh => \*STDOUT, -format => "fasta", );
# Prevent sequence lines wrapping in bioperl by using arbitrary large width:
$out_seq->width(1e9);
while ( my $seq = $in_seq->next_seq ) {
    my $id = $seq->id;
    $seq->id( "$id.new" );
    $seq->seq( lc $seq->seq );
    $out_seq->write_seq($seq);
}
' > out.fa
```

```
head in.fa out.fa
==> in.fa <==
>seq1
ACTGCTGACTGCTGACTGCTGACTGCTGACTGCTGACTGCTGACTGCTGACTGCTGACTGCTGACTGCTG
>seq2
ACTGCTGACTGCTGACTGCTGACTGCTGACTGCTGACTGCTGACTGCTGACTGCTGACTGCTGACTGCTG
>seq3
ACTGCTGACTGCTGACTGCTGACTGCTGACTGCTGACTGCTGACTGCTGACTGCTGACTGCTGACTGCTG

==> out.fa <==
>seq1.new
actgctgactgctgactgctgactgctgactgctgactgctgactgctgactgctgactgctgactgctg
>seq2.new
actgctgactgctgactgctgactgctgactgctgactgctgactgctgactgctgactgctgactgctg
>seq3.new
actgctgactgctgactgctgactgctgactgctgactgctgactgctgactgctgactgctgactgctg
```

You can install BioPerl, for example, using conda:

```
conda create --name bioperl perl-bioperl
```